# JavaScript＋HTMLで開発

Tags: javascript

HTML＋JavaScriptで出来ることって何ですか？
Androidアプリ、iOSアプリ等は作れるんですか？

Answer (score 2):

HTMLはWebページを記述する言語です。それだけでは文章や画像、リンクを表示するといったことしかできませんが、Javascriptを組み合わせることで「ボタンを押したらメッセージを表示する」とか「別のサーバーから取得した情報を同じページに展開する」とか、Webページに動きを持たせることができます。

基本的にはWebサーバーにブラウザからアクセスして表示・実行させるものですが、最近ではPC上やスマートフォン上で動くアプリを作るためにも使われるようになってきました。この場合、ブラウザの代わりに「HTMLを表示しJavascriptを実行する」土台が用意されているので、そこで動くように開発し、その土台とセットにして配布することになります。

具体的には、PC向けだとElectronやNW.js、スマートフォン向けにはApache CordovaやMonacaといったものが存在します。ブラウザを埋め込んだアプリを自分で作ることもあります。